# What is the meaning of elevator pitch?

Tags: meaning

In this sentence:

> What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

What's the meaning of elevator pitch, and what its meaning in this sentence specifically?

Comment: According to ngram, "elevator pitch" appeared first, but "elevator speech" is more common today.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember that questions on StackExchange should demonstrate your initial research effort. A simple web search for "elevator pitch" will show you a dictionary definition and a whole Wikipedia article, and then three million suggestions for how to craft one.

Comment: Adding my vote to the votes to close.  Saul, please see http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/elevatorpitch.asp and edit your question if you're still in doubt.

Comment: @aparente001 can you migrate this question? If so, please do it to English Language Learners

Comment: Sorry, Saul, I don't have moderator powers.  You could flag your question and make that request; I don't know if you'd be successful.  But I can help you here in the comments if you tell me what you're having trouble with.  I thought my link gave a great explanation.  What's tripping you up?

Answer (score 2):

Elevator pitches are brief sales pitches. They are called "elevator" because their brevity makes it possible to deliver to someone you are next to in the duration of an elevator ride.

The sentence could be expanded to something like "What brief sales pitch do we use to promote our site when only limited time is available?"